# Does mongoose prevent all NoSQL attacks?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

some times ago I found a few articles that keep saying that mongoose is prevention for NoSQL attacks but know I found a different article saying that mongoose won't prevent all NoSQL attacks. Well, so I am curious if mongoose is enough prevention from NoSQL attack for node app. Thank for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mongoose* is not intended to prevent NoSQL attacks. It is a *MongoDB* ODM that makes it easy for you, including organizing your database with schemas or query helper.
Inherently, it will help you avoid some security mistakes you might make without it, but that is not enough in itself.

First of all, you need to securize your MongoDB database and your system.

Note also that it is quite impossible to prevent "all" attacks in general.